# How do I determine the column position in a compound key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to identify all the primary keys in a db. The following code appears to do the job quite well:

```
SELECT i.name AS IndexName,
   OBJECT_NAME (ic.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
   COL_NAME (ic.OBJECT_ID, ic.column_id) AS ColumnName
FROM sys.indexes AS i
   INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
      ON i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1
```

The problem I have is that some of the keys are compound keys. This query identifies which keys are compound (multiple rows for a particular indexName in the sys.indexes table) but it does not show me the order. I need to know this because:

```
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[bl_id] ASC,
[fl_id] ASC,
[rm_id] ASC
)
```

is not the same as:

```
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[rm_id] ASC
[fl_id] ASC,
[bl_id] ASC,
```

)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

key_ordinal seems to do the trick:

```
SELECT i.name AS IndexName,
   OBJECT_NAME (ic.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
   COL_NAME (ic.OBJECT_ID, ic.column_id) AS ColumnName,
   ic.Key_ordinal as ColumnOrder
FROM sys.indexes AS i
   INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
      ON i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1
ORDER BY ic.OBJECT_ID, ic.Key_ordinal
```